# make div do -200px multiple times?

Tags: javascript, attributes, jquery-animate

I am trying to move a div -200px from his original position when I press a button. Now I want to be able to do this multiple times.

```js
function leftAnimate(){
        original = document.getElementById("sliderzelf").setAttribute("style", "margin-left: -200px;");
    }
```

This piece of code ( I assume, correct me if Im wrong.) really sets the attribute ONCE to -200px. Is there any way I can make this do -200px from every new starting position?

Comment: try **jQuery** $("#sliderzelf").css("margin-left","-200px");

Comment: I get the very same effect as with my own code sadly =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used the `jquery-animate` tag, I shall presume you have jQuery. In which case the following should work:

```
function leftAnimate() {
    $("#sliderzelf").css("margin-left", "-=200");
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I also use jquery. I shall try this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

call this function however you like, add a css transition on the element if you want it to slide or whatever. happy coding!

```
function leftAnimate(){
  var el = document.getElementById("section");
  var curMargin = window.getComputedStyle(el)['margin-left'].replace('px', '');
  var newPos = Number(curMargin - 200);
  original = el.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:" + newPos + "px;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you element is an absolute element, try use the Left instead margin-left, or
You can try with jQuery:

```
function leftAnimate(){
        var actualPosition = $("#sliderzelf").css("left");
        original = document.getElementById("sliderzelf").setAttribute("style", "margin-left: " + (actualPosition - 200).toString() + "px;");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript:

```js
function leftAnimate(){
  //get the button
  var btn = document.getElementById("sliderzelf");

  //get the current margin
  var currentMargin = btn.style.marginLeft.replace("px", "");

  //calculate the new margin
  var newMargin = currentMargin - 200;

  //check if the new margin is valid (optional)
  if (newMargin >= 0)
    btn.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: " + newMargin + "px;") //set the new margin
}
```

```html
<button id="sliderzelf" style="margin-left: 600px" onclick="leftAnimate()">
    Click me!
</button>
```

With jquery just change the function to:

```
 $("#sliderzelf").css('margin-left', '-= 200');
```